# How do I remove a dynamically added element after 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, settimeout

I'm making a simple game where users should click flies to remove them from the screen. The user should not click the cat when it drops, and I'm hoping to make the cat gif disappear (remove itself from the DOM) after 5 seconds.

I apologize if this has been answered before. I'm having a hard time solving this as my experience is very limited. This is my first question/post ever. Thanks for any and all feedback :)!

```
$('.square').each(function(i){
    if (($('.square').eq(i)).has(".cat")){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.square').eq(i).find('img').remove();
    }, 5000);       
};
```

^this is the code I tried to write... the .square class are the squares that make up the table like grid of divs... and the .cat class refers to an image dropped.

The problem is multiple cats can be dropped on the screen at the same time.

I need the page to recognize when a cat is dropped, set a timeout for 5 seconds when that occurs, and then remove that particular cat from the page after 5 seconds.

Thanks for the help :)!

```
var randomize = function (x) {return Math.floor(Math.random()*x)};

var startFunk = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.square:empty')[randomize(($('.square:empty').length))].innerHTML = dropArray[randomize(dropArray.length)];
        startFunk();
    }, 500);
};
```

Comment: You'd probably want a setTimeout in whatever code that is actually dropping the cat

Comment: You're on the right track, but you need to show us your drop code.

Comment: var randomize = function (x) {return Math.floor(Math.random()*x)};

var timer = 550;

var startFunk = function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
  $('.square:empty')[randomize(($('.square:empty').length))].innerHTML = 
  dropArray[randomize(dropArray.length)];
//  if (timer>100){
  timer -= 1;
//  };
  startFunk();
 }, timer);
};

Comment: sorry... I'm so new to this... about to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May help

```
$('.square').each(function(i){
    if ($(this).find('.cat').length > 0){
        $(this).find('.cat').delay(5000).fadeOut(0, function(){
            // change ..^... with img 
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

[**DEMO Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/pdL0qvdg/)

Comment: @TreyHarding it up to what you want to do .. if you drop .cat class and want to remove it after 5 second of dropping . the answer is yes .. each time you drop .cat  you should run this code

Comment: @TreyHarding you can also play around .fadeOut(0, function(){}); change 0 with 1000 or 2000 to get a nice fadeOut() if you want that .. Good luck :)

Comment: What a great community this is! I'm so appreciative for the responses. Thanks @Mohamed-Yousef!

Answer (score 0):

```
var startFunk = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var sqr = $('.square:empty')[randomize(($('.square:empty').length))];
        sqr.innerHTML = dropArray[randomize(dropArray.length)];
        sqr.has('.cat').delay(5000).empty();
        startFunk();
    }, 500);
};
```

And get rid of the `$('.square').each(function(i){...` part.

Comment: Thanks Samurai. I'll check this out too! Thrilled to have gotten so much help!